# Achieving hover effect with text and icons in jquery

Tags: jquery

Can someone please give me some advice on how to make a rollover effect like the one on this site:

http://canopy.co/

when you rollover the tiles, a shadow drops over the tile and icons and text are layered on top. I'm not sure if it's using jquery or css but I think it would be a lot easier with jquery.

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved just using the CSS3.

You can use css :hover selector. Also, check the CSS3 transitions: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/

You can also play with CSS3 shadows, for example here: http://css3gen.com/box-shadow/ then just copy/paste desired shadow look..

Comment: But doesn't the hover attribute only change the properties of the div that is selected? I want it to display something on top of it as a result.